# LuaTeX: Method equivalent to node.id("<type_name>") for subtypes, and reverse mapping

Tags: luatex

Is there a method in luatex distribution that provides an equivalent of `node.id("<type_name>")` for subtypes? A method like `node.subtype_id("<type_name>","<subtype_name>")`? That would be much cleaner than manually copying number equivalent of subtype names from luatex manual. Also, how can one build a reverse mapping in Lua instead of writing a nested table manually? Reverse mapping will return string for type/subtype number. `return (str: "type_name") node.typename(<type_number>)`, and `return (str: "subtype_name") node.subtypename(<type_number>,<subtype_number>)`. I can write these tables by manually entering the values from Luatex manual, though IMO a more automated way that picks up these values from a central place where these values are defined in luatex codebase is more reliable. It will also guard against any future interface change, and new types/subtypes mappings will automatically become available without having to do any manual maintenance work (thus reducing possible bugs, and saving debug time).

Comment: For example `table.swapped(node.subtypes("glue"))["mathskip"]` (Warning, inefficient! cache the result of `table.swapped` for each node id).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks a lot, yes was looking for something like that.